# Issues controlling 3rd party program with SendKeys when admin access required

Tags: vb.net, uac, sendkeys

I have made a program that controls a 3rd party program with `SendKeys` and mouse-clicks (`mouse_event`).

It worked fine on the program until the company updated it, and made it require admin access (and prompt UAC when opening). Even after disabling UAC, my program cannot send any input when their program is focused.

I know that it is trying to send the clicks/keypresses, since if I open notepad instead of the program, it starts going.

I am wondering if there is any way that `SendKeys` can work even with a program that requires admin access. I have tried running my program as an administrator, but with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: As this would effectively break UAC, I'd say it's unlikely. . . .

Comment: Please see this post [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665952/sendkeys-send-is-blocked)

Comment: @Zaggler I've looked through that post, and I don't think my issue was related to an outdated .net framework.

Comment: @peterG but I am allowed (and have) disabled UAC on windows. I am not looking for a way to avoid it, and I have admin access.